# Add date to multiple cells based off another column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I'm trying to create a Pivot Table from this exported report. Screenshot:

[image]

However, each line does not have a date on it.

I've attempted to create a new column to add the dates to each line, but my formula only works on the first blank line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this work for you?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3);C2;B3)
```

[image]